# Creating common selector of 2 dom paths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a webscraper where the users selects information they want scraped.

I have 2 paths of dom elements.  Based on those I'd like to select any other elements that match that pattern.

`body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > p > font`
 body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > p > font`

How would I use javascript to create a dynamic selector generator that would get any other div in the same column that matches that pattern?

Sometimes it could be a table, other times it could be from a nested set of divs.

The path is being generated from a click event, so if using the event data rather than a static path works better I'm open to that.

Here's an example of a sample output I need from the function. `body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody td:nth-child(2) > p > font`

Notice the space between `tbody` & `td:nth-child(2)` rather than `>`

Comment: Have you tried `querySelectorAll`? `var _div = document.querySelectorAll("body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody td:nth-child(2) > div > font");`

Comment: It won't always be the same td child though.  It'll move around depending on what column the user is selecting.

Comment: shouldn't it be better to have a specific class for that element, so you target them easily table__paragraph-font

Comment: I'm building a webscraper where the user can select info.  The example path I gave is just from a random site I chose.  I updated my description to reflect the extra context info.

Comment: Could you provide an example structure of your HTML page and what you meant by table columns?

Answer (score 0):

Once you find your `<font>` element (please don't use `<font>` though!), you can check the column index:

```js
const td = fontElement.closest('td');
const columnIndex = [...td.parentNode].indexOf(td);
```

Now, you can construct your new selector using `columnIndex`.

Comment: It won't always be within a table that a user selects. Sometimes it could be a nested div, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you get the idea :) You can edit that snippet to your needs.

Comment: Without specific example it's difficult to give you solution. From my understanding, you need to read particular column. That's what I did in my answer - I gave you `columnIndex`. You can use it in your final selector's `:nth-child`.